# JAVA Regex with XML

Tags: java

i have this String and i need to get the attribut Ccy to TtlIntrBkSttlmAmt with a regex.

Can you help me to have the best pattern ?

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns = "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.02" xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <FIToFICstmrCdtTrf>
        <GrpHdr>
            <MsgId>XXXXXXXXXXX</MsgId>
            <CreDtTm>2013-07-23T16:30:14</CreDtTm>
            <NbOfTxs>0</NbOfTxs>
            <TtlIntrBkSttlmAmt Ccy = "EUR">0000.00</TtlIntrBkSttlmAmt>
            <IntrBkSttlmDt>2013-07-24</IntrBkSttlmDt>
            <SttlmInf>
                <SttlmMtd>CLRG</SttlmMtd>
                <SttlmAcct>
                    <Id>
                        <IBAN>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</IBAN>
                    </Id>
                </SttlmAcct>
                <ClrSys>
                    <Prtry>XXXXX</Prtry>
                </ClrSys>
            </SttlmInf>
        </GrpHdr>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why Regex? What's wrong with XPath?

Comment: Why dont you use XML Parsing library?

Comment: Because a work with an ETL and a can't use a Dom parser !

Comment: [You don't parse (x|h)tml with regex.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: what about DOM Parser ?

Comment: Define ETL and tell us exactly why it prevents you from using an XML parser. I have a hard time understanding why those are incompatible.

Comment: I'am on a ternary opérator , i can't change that because i use an ETL. I have 2 solution : Create a static function or get it on my ternary opérator if it's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use a Regex, use an XML parser instead. Anyway...

```
(?!= <TtlIntrBkSttlmAmt)Ccy = "[A-Z]+"
```

Should do the trick. Edit the [A-Z] group to meet your specific needs.

Comment: Thank you for your solution but finally i have create a static fonction which convert my String to Document XML and get my attribut

Answer (score 1):

```
?? = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder()
         .parse( new InputSource( new StringReader( XMLLine ) ) )
         .getElementsByTagName("TtlIntrBkSttlmAmt")
         .item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("Ccy").getNodeValue();
```